# Multiple Binding

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

In my WPF Caliburn.Micro application, I have a datagrid and a checkbox with a corresponding ModelView bool property. I need to bind the checkbox to one of the datagrid's fields OneWay (which is easy). But also I want to bind the same checkbox to the property OneWayToSource. Could you please tell me how I can do that? I don't see how Multibinding can help here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is a checkbox per row of the `DataGrid`, or a checkbox for a row with a particular id or index. Either way, you can use `TwoWay` binding, which will be the default anyway if your view model property has a getter and setter.

Your view model property should point to the instance of the record that the `DataGrid` is binding to.

E.g.

**View Model**

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> MyGridItems { get; set; }

public MyViewModel()
{
   this.MyGridItems = ...
   this.MySpecialItem = this.MyGridItems[0];
}

public Item MySpecialItem 
{
   get { return this.mySpecialItem; }
   set { this.mySpecialItem = value; // notify of property change here }
}
```

**View**

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding MySpecialItem.MyBooleanProperty}" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it seems to me that it is not what I want. I must have been not clear. My DataGrid's source is an ObservableCollection, like you said. I want one of the fields to be the source for my checkbox. I don't want the checkbox to change the DataGrid contents, i.e. the ObservableCollection. Thus I need to bind the checkbox to that collection OneWay. But also I want the checkbox to be able to change the value of its corresponding property in the ModalView, so that I could use it to save data in the database after the user changed it.

Comment: I'm still not quite clear - when you say ModalView, I assume you mean 'view model'. If this is the case, why don't you just initialise the value of your view model boolean property (for example in the view model constructor), and then TwoWay bind that view model property to the CheckBox. When the check box is checked/unchecked, the view model property will update appropriately (your vm should implement INotifyPropertyChanged and you should invoke the PropertyChanged event in the setter).

Comment: Yes, I meant ViewModel, of course. Yes, I can bind the checkbox to a property, and thus always get the IsChecked value of the checkbox. But besides that, I need the checkbox's IsChecked to be set based on the selected value in the DataGrid, not based on the boolean property mentioned above. Thus the checkbox gets its value from the selected item in the DataGrid, and boolean property gets its value from the checkbox to use it for an update.

Comment: Ok, so you should bind the SelectedItem of the DataGrid to a property of type 'Item' or whatever your bound data item type is on the view model. Then in the setter for this property, you can set the value of your view model boolean property to the property value of the selected item.